# Leverage browser caching (internal)

Tags: apache, caching, pagespeed

I'm getting the below with PageSpeed Insights:

[image: Leverage browser caching]

But in my Apache site configuration I have:

```
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>

             ExpiresActive On
             ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
             ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
             ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 weeks"
             ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
             ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
             ExpiresByType image/* "access plus 2 weeks"

    </IfModule>
```

`mod_expires` is enabled.
And seems to work, since other css, jpg, png, ... files are cached. But some js and css files are not. What am I doing wrong?

You can try at http://itransformer.es

Answer (score 4):

I believe that apache uses
application/javascript to represent js files

```
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
```

If you check in apaches mime.types 
text/javascript is commented out.

I would additionally suggest that you look at optimizing your sites images

```
http://itransformer.es/public/img/carrete.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 2135x1555 to 300x219. Serving a scaled image could save 561.5KiB (98% reduction).
http://itransformer.es/public/img/logo.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 608x99 to 500x81. Serving a scaled image could save 29.3KiB (33% reduction).
http://itransformer.es/public/img/carrete2.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 2000x298 to 1903x284. Serving a scaled image could save 3.7KiB (10% reduction).
http://itransformer.es/public/img/gplus.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 62x64 to 35x36. Serving a scaled image could save 1.9KiB (68% reduction).
http://itransformer.es/public/img/tw.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 62x64 to 35x36. Serving a scaled image could save 1.5KiB (68% reduction).
http://itransformer.es/public/img/fb.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 62x64 to 35x36. Serving a scaled image could save 1.0KiB (68% reduction).
```

They are some big  images to load on a landing page and really slow the first acces load times. make sure when your looking at the page load you turn off your own browser cache to simulate someone entering for the first time.

Good Luck
Narimm

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but unfortunately `application/javascript` doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like it did work. I get these headers now from your server:

`Cache-Control: max-age=1209600`,
`Expires: Mon, 16 Dec 2013 16:19:24 GMT`,
`Content-Type: application/javascript`

Comment: Yes. But it should throw a 304 response (not modified), and it throws a 200 OK response. So the caching is not working.